# pass Int to C function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am writing swift code & need to invoke a C function.

```
var idx = 5
//ERROR: Cannot invoke c_func with argument list of type '(Int)'
c_func(idx)
```

The C function signature is:

```
void c_func(int idx)
```

So, my question is how can I pass swift `Int` to C function which accepts `int` as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C type `int` is mapped to Swift as

```
/// The C 'int' type.
typealias CInt = Int32
```

Therefore you have to declare the variable as `CInt`:

```
var idx : CInt = 5
c_func(idx)
```

or convert the `Int` to `CInt`:

```
var idx = 5
c_func(CInt(idx))
```

(Of course you can use `Int32` instead if you prefer to emphasize that it is a fixed-size
integer type.)

More information about the mappings between (Objective-)C types
and Swift types can be found in the ["Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html) documentation.